# Leap Motion Controller.RemoveListener() called in Dispose() hangs

Tags: multithreading, controller, dispose, freeze, leap-motion

I've started developing a Leap Motion app and this is driving me nuts. Whenever I exit the application, the code responsible for cleaning up the Leap Motion controller hangs on me.

```
public void CleanUp()
{
    _lmController.RemoveListener(_lmListener);
    _lmController.Dispose();
}
```

I create both the controller and the listener in my Main Thread in a presenter class:

```
public MainViewPresenter(IMainView view, IApplicationController applicationController)
{
    _view = view;
    _applicationController = applicationController;
    _view.Presenter = this;

    _lmListener.Frame += _lmListener_Frame;
    _lmController.AddListener(_lmListener);
}
```

The Cleanup() method is also a presenter method called on the view's FormClosing event. The weird thing is that it works perfectly fine when I call it from `_listener_Frame()`, which runs on a separate, Leap Motion-created no-name thread!

`_lmListener_Frame()` itself resides in the presenter. It just gets data from `_lmController`, creates a view model and sends it to the view, which in turn uses `Invoke` to update the display data.

I've tried calling the CleanUp stuff in Dispose() (both the view and the presenter (not redundant of course)) and that also doesn't work.

I admit that I'm not an expert in threading, but I can't see how there's any conflict going on here, and why RemoveListener works from controller thread, but not from the Main Thread, where the listener was actually added. Any help is appreciated!

#### **SOLUTION**

Completely by chance, I've found the solution today! It turns out that the "Invoke" call was the culprit, and it should've been BeginInvoke all this time, although this isn't mentioned anywhere in the WinForms setup guide. I'm guessing it was causing a deadlock with the controller thread and after the first GUI update it was bound to crash.

Answer (score 0):

In a Windows forms Application, the following worked for me:

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        try
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (components != null)
                {
                    components.Dispose();
                }
                this.controller.RemoveListener(this.listener);
                this.controller.Dispose();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote it awhile ago, though, and don't remember why it needed to be more complicated than what you tried. (Full example here: https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/csharp/devguide/Project_Setup_WinForms.html)

Comment: That's actually what I tried first, since it's in the WinForms setup guide. It ended up the same way! Also, I don't want the LM stuff residing in my views, I'd rather leave that to core & presentation.

Comment: I looked into it further and noticed that Invoke worked without error on x86, but leads to a hang on x64.